# using cake htmlhelper in custom class

Tags: cakephp

I have a custom class which I store in /app/Lib and I'd like to use the htmlhelper but as the class is not extending anything the reference to $this as in `$this->Html->link` gives the error: Call to a member function link() on a non-object

how can I use this helper from within my own class?

which is:

```
<?php
class Tree {

  private $level = 0;

  public function show_tree($tree_array) {
    $this->level++;
    $style = ($this->level==1) ? ' class="sortable"':'';
    echo "<ol".$style.">\n";
    foreach ($tree_array as $t) {
        echo "<li id=\"list_".$t['Category']['id']."\">\n";         
        echo "<div>".$t['Category']['name'];?>
        echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $t['Category']['id']));
        echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('action' => 'edit', $t['Category']['id']));
        echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $t['Category']['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $t['Category']['id']));
        echo "</span>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
        if (!empty($t['children'])) $this->show_tree($t['children']);
        echo "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ol>\n";
    $this->level--;
   }


 }
```

Comment: You're not instantiating the Helper correctly if you get that error. Show the code. Furthermore it sounds like your approach is wrong if you think you have to use a helper inside that lib.

Comment: why would need a helper in a lib? shouldnt you be using Router::url instead to create urls? or create a custom helper and use the Html helper this way?

Comment: my class is just a simple recursive function that outputs a nested list. I just wanted to add some CRUD links to the output. I'll add the code above if it helps.

Comment: jep, it should still be a helper then. the scope clearly is the view level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code you clearly want a helper, not a lib.

Extend the html helper or use it within your custom helper, named NestedListHelper for example. This is the right way in the MVC context and will also be the most less code to write.

Take a look at this TreeHelper, it will also generated nested lists based on a tree structure, it might be similar to what you try todo: https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/master/View/Helper/TreeHelper.php

Comment: Thank you, making a new helper that extends AppHelper and adding the helpers array of the core ones I wanted to use worked. New to MVC and cake...